# iOS Sum values in Table View without core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, parsing, sum

Is there a way to sum the values entered into a table view cell without using Core Data?  I am currently using Parse.  I guess a better question would be how can I get the sum using Parse?  I'm really scratching my head on this one.  Hand holding may be required.

Comment: What do you mean by sum here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the Key-Value Coding collection operators. Suppose the row data for the table are a bunch of instances of class `Entry` and are collected in an `NSArray` named `data`. Further suppose each `Entry` object has an `NSNumber` property named `cost` and this is what you want to sum. Then you can do so as follows:

```
NSNumber *sum = [data valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.cost"];
```

Just to be clear: this does require that the values you wish to sum are properties of the objects that are backing each row.

Comment: Matthew, thanks for the help.  I read about key-value coding last week, but it took your example to make sense.  Apple's example "NSNumber *amountSum = [transactions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];" did not make sense because I could not find out where they were getting the valueForKeyPath.  Thanks again for your help!